# Why is the physicsBody bigger than visual model in sceneView?

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, physics

I am working on the game with spaceship flying around earth and destroying objects. I wanted to add some reaction when object hit the spaceship but the contact is detected before it "hit" visual model of the spaceship. I found out that the physicsbody of the node is bigger than visual model. What should I do to set it on the same size?
Here's some more info:

- I created model built of many basic shapes/nodes in SceneKit editor in Xcode
- I set physics body in the editor with options: dynamic type, default shape, bounding box, scale: 1.
- There's part of my code that do something with the ship node:

  ```
    shipNode = scene.rootNode.childNode(withName: "ship", recursively: true)!
    shipNode.physicsBody!.physicsShape = SCNPhysicsShape(node: shipNode, options: nil)
    shipNode.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = 4
  ```

[screen of UI of my game, with physicsshapes visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnMTZ.png)

Comment: So it looks like red/green lines are defining your "bounding box" so that you have a clear visual of what SceneKit thinks the size of it is AND your hits correspond with that bounding box, correct?  Assuming you can also see bounding boxes for the objects that are colliding with your ship and those also correspond to what SK thinks the size of it is?

Comment: I'm going to assume that's true so that you don't have to wait for an answer.  Take out your model as how it is built could be the cause.  Substitute something simple like an SCNBox so that you have a known quantity to work with.

Comment: @Voltan Thanks for your tip! I feel like I should've checked it in first place. I turned out to be the problem with importing SceneKit scene with the ship model to my main scene. Before, the spaceship was too big so I changed scale of "ship reference" in main scene. In this situation textures got smaller but physicsbody didn't. After your tip, I changed the size of the ship in original .scn file and it solved all problems.

Comment: Excellent, good to hear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to close this out, we should probably mark it as solved;

Before, the spaceship was too big so I changed scale of "ship reference" in main scene. In this situation textures got smaller but physicsbody didn't. After your tip, I changed the size of the ship in original .scn file and it solved all problems